# DNN portal alias with internal IP

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm having trouble figuring out if/how I can an internal webserver setup for testing with mutliple DNN portals. I'm pretty new to DotNetNuke, so I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible.

My server is at an IP of 192.168.15.16. I have the main portal set up with a portal alias of this IP. That site works fine. But then I have a couple other sites (lets call them A and B) to configure.

I'd like to navigate to 192.168.15.16/A and 192.168.15.16/B to view these sites. Portal aliases to these don't seem to cut it. I get a 404 error and I believe it's because IIS adds A or B to the physical path, which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to set this up? Maybe something I need to change in IIS? Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: This may need migrated to Server Fault, but I agree it is in a gray area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) On any machine that you need to access the test sites, Edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to include:

```
     192.168.15.16    A
     192.168.15.16    B
```

2) Set the portal alias of site A to "A"

3) Set the portal alias of site B to "B"

4) Access site A via http://A/

5) Access site B via http://B/

6) Edit the bindings of your IIS Site to include "B" and "A" host headers

**Notes**

- If you have a local domain controller, you can probably tell it to resolve "A" and "B" to the proper IP.
- I use this same method on our dev machines, but I've yet to include multiple portals on the same DNN installation. I am assuming this will work.

Comment: It works, thanks! I was a bit worried until I added the host headers and it started working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the answer to include a step 6, accordingly.