# How to run new web site on DotNetNuke?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I succesfully installed DNN on my PC and it perfectly works by the url: http://localhost/dotnetnuke

So I created new site localhost/test2 in DNN and try to run it 
http://localhost/test2

it says: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

So, as I understand my alias is wrong, what alias should I set up to run site on my localhost ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing configuration, you simply need to add another Virtual Directory to IIS pointing /test2 to the exactly same folder that /DotNetNuke is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808775/127880)

1) On any machine that you need to access the test sites, Edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to include:

```
     192.168.15.16    A
     192.168.15.16    B
```

2) Set the portal alias of site A to "A"

3) Set the portal alias of site B to "B"

4) Access site A via http://A/

5) Access site B via http://B/

6) Edit the bindings of your IIS Site to include "B" and "A" host headers

**Notes**

- If you have a local domain controller, you can probably tell it to resolve "A" and "B" to the proper IP.
- I use this same method on our dev machines, but I've yet to include multiple portals on the same DNN installation. I am assuming this will work.